# How to add interface on autogenerated jaxb elements by xsdtojava?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I want to add a super `interface` for a class autogenerated by `jaxb` and `xsdtojava`.

Problem: I can only add the interface on the root element (which I don't want, but just for testing purpose).

The element where I want to apply the inheritance is `thelistelement`.

The `xsd` I have not control of.

```
<xs:schema>
    <xs:element name="myRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="thelist">
                   <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                         <xs:element name="thelistelement" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    ...
```

binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings    
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc inheritance"
    jaxb:version="2.1">

    <!-- this works -->
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/my.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='myRequest']">
                    <inheritance:implements>MyInterface</inheritance:implements>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <!-- this does NOT work -->
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/my.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='thelistelement']">
                    <inheritance:implements>MyInterface</inheritance:implements>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Running with `<extensionArg>-Xinheritance</extensionArg>`.

Output should be:

```
...
List<Thelistelement> thelist;

class Thelistelement implements MyInterface {

}
```

But the interface is missing on the list element class. Why then does it work on the root element `myRequest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add an `/xs:complexType` to the node. Don't know why that worked though.

Important to note the single slash before the complexType!

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="xsd/my.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='thelistelement']/xs:complexType">
                <inheritance:implements>MyInterface</inheritance:implements>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Must be path to complexType, because XJC generate class for xs:complexType, not for xs:element.